# Subtracting a variable in a loop in Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to calculate how many rounds can a player play lotto and joker games with a fixed amount of money.

```
public static void example () {
    int money = 200;
    int lottoCost = 4;
    int jokerCost = 3;
    int costTogether = lottoCost+jokerCost;
    int rounds = 0;

    for (int i = money; i <= 0; rounds++) {
        money = money-costTogether;
    }

    System.out.println("With " + money + " euros, you can play "
                        + rounds + " rounds.");
    System.out.println("");

}
```

That code currently prints the text "With 200 euros, you can play 0 rounds."
So it doesn't add a +1 to the **rounds** variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Loop is never entered that is why you get what you see.

Comment: Try doing the for-loop on paper.

Comment: Why do you use a for loop?

Comment: If you fix the loop as suggested by others, your output will no longer be correct, since you modify the `money` variable.

Comment: Also, you don't need a loop to calculate the number of rounds, normal division will do the trick (and if you use this, then you incidentally "fix" the bug noticed in my previous comment).

Comment: Yes, I tried the while loop as suggested but because it changes the money variable the output is "With 4 euros you can play 28 rounds." Where the 4 euros is the money that is left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stopping condition is wrong, so the loop is never exectued. You should use `>=` instead. Also, you never change nor use `i`.

Here is a corrected version, using `currMoney` instead of `i` to be more meaningful.

```
int rounds = 0;
for (int currMoney = money; currMoney >= costTogether; currMoney -= costTogether) {
    rounds++;
}
```

But obviously here, you only need a simple division as @Fredszaq pointed out in his answer:

```
int rounds = money / costTogether;
```

Comment: The money variable should not be changed since it is printed out later on.

Comment: Indeed, I thought the OP was printing the remaining money, I hadn't read ;-)

Comment: This indeed did the trick! Of course I want a new variable to be used :) Thanks to everyone for really fast answers!

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is good to use the same variable in the 3 parts of the for. Note that the loop initialization part (the first one `int i = money`) is only run once, and you don't modify i during the loop. Furthermore, the condition is false from the beginning (`200 < 0`) so the loop is not even run once

I think what you are looking for is a simple int division, just replace your for block with this :

```
rounds = money / costTogether;
```

Comment: Upvoted for the simple answer regarding the original problem instead of the OP's current little bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for`-loop is not defined correctly. `i` starts at `money` = 200. You want to repeat the loop as long as `i <= 0`. So you require i starting at 200 while not being larger than 0. That's why your loop isn't executed at all.

Instead prefer a `while` loop for your case. It is more readable:

```
while (money >= costTogether) {
    money = money - costTogether;
    rounds++;
}
```

If you want to use a for loop, you can declare it like that:

```
for (int i = money; i >= costTogether; i -= costTogether) {
    rounds++;
}
```

Comment: He is doing `i <= 0`?

Comment: This is what his code says. Anyway using a for loop does not seem too appropriated for his case.

Answer (score 0):

This condition `i <= 0` is never true and probably dont get incremented

i guess its a typo ,

Greater and Lessthan you need to be aware as they change context .

Comment: Infinite loop here though.

Comment: @Evan oops ! i didnt see to it thanks . feel free to update it to make it clear

Answer (score -1):

You're only incrementing `rounds`, in a roundabout way, when the loop runs.

The loop runs while `i <= 0` - `i` starts equal to `money`, which equals 200, so the loop never runs and the rounds value is not incremented.

You're also not changing `i` in the loop - I suspect you'd rather want while `i >= 0` and decrement `i` in the loop?

```
for (int i = money; i >= 0; rounds++) {
    money = money-costTogether;
    i--;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `i` starts at `money` but is not decremented by the right amount at each turn.